# htaccess code for redirect all internal links

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My previous website address is:
qaz.com/home-page/

I want to redirect all old address to a new domain:
wsx.com/home-page/

I could do this for main address:
qaz.com redirected to wsx.com/home-page/ correctly with this code:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/wsx\.com\/home-page\/" [R=301,L]
```

but internal links such as:
https://qaz.com/home-page/professional-theme/ did not redirect to
https://wsx.com/home-page/professional-theme/

My website CMS is WordPress.
can you help to do this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this 1:1 ( qaz.com/anything <> wsx.com/anything ) rewrite rule on top of .htaccess file in your Wordpress folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?qaz\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://wsx.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or all links from qaz.com to wsx.com/home-page/ ( qaz.com/anything <> wsx.com/home-page/ )

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?qaz\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://wsx.com/home-page/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Redirect` directive instead of mod_rewrite:

```
Rewrite / https://wsx.com/
```

If both servernames are served from a single VHost config:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'wsx.com'">
    Rewrite / https://wsx.com/
</If>
```

Comment: @serversetupco You can put this in any config file. Redirect directive is accepted in all contexts (server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess). Check docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

Answer (score 0):

This would be the closest answer to your precise question:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HOST_NAME} ^qaz\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?home-page/(.+)$ https://wsx.com/home-page/$1 [R=301,QSA]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).